# What is the name of such notation?

Tags: syntax, bnf, notation

[JSON web site](https://json.org) uses very clear notation to describe JSON's syntax:

[image: http://www.json.org/object.gif]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/object.gif))</sub>

What is the name of such notation? Is this is just a graphical presentation of BNF or it has it's own name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called [Syntax Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) (or railroad diagrams)

"are a way to represent a context-free grammar. They represent a graphical alternative to Backus–Naur Form or EBNF"

Answer (score 2):

they are called "railroad diagrams"